# Connection problems in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, server

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\Blog\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

Someone knows, why did this happen?

Comment: This is something to do with your pc/hosting server setup, not Laravel it's self.

Comment: check in your project folder "server.php" file is missing ?

Comment: Yes, right. It seems that what makes the 'server.php' file missing is considered the virus by the anti-virus I use. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project folder, the `server.php` file is missing so you got this error

The solution will to create another project then copy the newly created **server.php** this will solve it.

Another Solution is:

1. Open the link: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php
2. Copy all code
3. Open Notepad and paste your copy code
4. save Notepad file and set name **server.php**
5. Copy the *server.php* file and paste it inside your Laravel project

Run your project again in browser Now you will not get an error and the Laravel project will work properly.

Comment: thank you very much , now my project is running smoothly